# Vue.js - how to hide an image with the hover event on it and show another?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have two images whose behavior I want to see next.
By default the image will be shown with the name 'home' and with the event 'mouseover' I want to hide and show the image with the name 'blackhome'.
I have the two images shown on screen and there's nothing happens with the mouse events
I don't know if this is possible.
Here's a codepen link with the issue
https://codepen.io/CharlieJS/pen/gOrayzW

this is my template

```
                      <li class="nav-item" @mouseover="homeLink = !homelink" @mouseleave="!homeLink" >
                        <a class='nav-link home'  href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <img v-if="homeLink" class="logo" src="../../assets/home.png">
                        <img v-if="!homelink" src="../../assets/blackhome.png">
                        </a>
                      </li>
```

and my script

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
     
      homeLink: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
      auth () {
        return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
      }
    },
  methods: {
    onLogout() {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help

Comment: your code seems working, what's the issue ? i think you should do `<li class="nav-item" @mouseover="homeLink = true" @mouseleave="homeLink=false" >`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have the two images shown on screen and there's nothing wrong with the mouse events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `v-if` and `v-else` as follows  :

```
<li class="nav-item" @mouseover="homeLink = !homelink" @mouseleave="homeLink=false" >
  <a class='nav-link home'  href="https://www.google.com/">
     <img v-if="homeLink" class="logo" src="../../assets/home.png"/>
    <img v-else src="../../assets/blackhome.png"/>
   </a>
</li>
```

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {

      homeLink: false
    }
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li class="nav-item" @mouseover="homeLink = !homelink" @mouseleave="homeLink=false">
    <a class='nav-link home' href="https://www.google.com/">
      <img v-if="homeLink" class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=244" />
      <img v-else src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1024" />
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```